# CMake Error: The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, compiler

I have found similar discussions from google but didn't work for me. I want to use a bioinformatics package called pompd. At the first use, the program will automatically compile another application called **toulbar2**. However, the following error appeared during the compilation:

```
git checkout ../src/ToulbarVersion.hpp
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/tam/script/pompd-master/positive/exes/tb2-submodule" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'toulbar2' failed
make: *** [toulbar2] Error 1
```

Does anyone has any idea how to resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you `git clone --recursive ...` the pompd repo? To me this sounds like you didn't get the submodule.